# WPF - Bring application to front from system tray

Tags: wpf, singleton, user32, notifyicon

I am using **System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon** to minimize my app to system tray. I wanted to **bring back the application to front when user tries to open another instance** of it.

The code from [**this site**](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2976/Detect-if-another-process-is-running-and-bring-it) works fine if the first instance of app is hidden behind other apps, but not when minimized to system tray.

How can I implement this with WPF?

Answer (score 1):

You Can acheive this by registering click event for the notify icon, you can

```
  private void SetSystemTrayIcon()
    {

        System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon notifyIcon = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
        {
            Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(sri.Stream),
            Visible = true
        };
        notifyIcon.Click += NotifyIcon_Click;
    }

    private void NotifyIcon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var mainWindow = Application.Current.Windows[0];
        mainWindow.Show();
    }
```

I hope this can help you

Comment: Thanks for your solution. :) But what I wanted is to invoke similar functionality when user runs another instance of the app, not when clicking on the icon in system tray.